# How do I rotate a css variable using the setInterval method in javascript? Ive tried so many different ways and have come up short

Tags: javascript, rotation, setinterval

Ive tried to copy code, nothing. Ive watched tutorials and there are always things in them that are beyond my knowledge and not explained, therefore leaving me even more confused. Youtube, tuts, google, googling stackoverflow questions, cant seem to figure it out. All i need is for a little push start and small explanation of the suggestions. Thank you.

This is my CSS. Ive already gotten the circle with the notches around it. its all i want rotating. no clock in here and dont plan to have one. I just want the circle with notches around ( kind of like a clock ) to rotate. The only "tools" i can think that would be useful are setInterval, my css variable '--rotate' and the new Date and getSeconds properties. i realize my code is all over the place but thats why im here, to learn and accomplish.

```
.notch_container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;

}


.notch_container .notch {
    --rotate: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    transform: rotate(var(--rotate));
}


.notch_container .notch1 {
    --rotate: 15deg;
}

.notch_container .notch2 {
    --rotate: 45deg;
}

.notch_container .notch3 {
    --rotate: 75deg;
}

.notch_container .notch4 {
    --rotate: 105deg;
}

.notch_container .notch5 {
    --rotate: 135deg;
}

.notch_container .notch6 {
    --rotate: 165deg;
}

.notch_container .notch7 {
    --rotate: 195deg;
}

.notch_container .notch8 {
    --rotate: 225deg;
}

.notch_container .notch9 {
    --rotate: 255deg;
}

.notch_container .notch10 {
    --rotate: 285deg;
}

.notch_container .notch11 {
    --rotate: 315deg;
}

.notch_container .notch12 {
    --rotate: 345deg;
}


This is my "javascript" that ive failed to get to function.


setInterval(setNotches, 1000);

const notches = document.querySelector('notch_container');

function setNotches() {
    dateToday = (new Date());
    notchRevolve = dateToday.getSeconds() / 60;

    startRotate(notches, notchRevolve);
}

function startRotate(document, rotationDegrees) {
    document.style.setProperty('--rotate', rotationDegrees * 360);
}

setNotches();
```

Answer (score 0):

you code seems fine the only mistake you made is that you are setting just the integer value what you need is to append deg.

```
function startRotate(document, rotationDegrees) {
    document.style.setProperty('--rotate', (rotationDegrees * 360) + 'deg');
}
```

plus you need to have transform rotate property on .notch_container

```js
setInterval(setNotches, 1000);

const notches = document.querySelector('.notch_container');

function setNotches() {
    dateToday = (new Date());
    notchRevolve = dateToday.getSeconds() / 60;

    startRotate(notches, notchRevolve);
}

function startRotate(document, rotationDegrees) {
    document.style.setProperty('--rotate', (rotationDegrees * 360) + 'deg');
}

setNotches();
```

```css
.notch_container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(var(--rotate));
    }
    .notch_container .notch {
        --rotate: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    transform: rotate(var(--rotate));
}


.notch_container .notch1 {
    --rotate: 15deg;
}

.notch_container .notch2 {
    --rotate: 45deg;
}

.notch_container .notch3 {
    --rotate: 75deg;
}

.notch_container .notch4 {
    --rotate: 105deg;
}

.notch_container .notch5 {
    --rotate: 135deg;
}

.notch_container .notch6 {
    --rotate: 165deg;
}

.notch_container .notch7 {
    --rotate: 195deg;
}

.notch_container .notch8 {
    --rotate: 225deg;
}

.notch_container .notch9 {
    --rotate: 255deg;
}

.notch_container .notch10 {
    --rotate: 285deg;
}

.notch_container .notch11 {
    --rotate: 315deg;
}

.notch_container .notch12 {
    --rotate: 345deg;
}
```

```html
<div class="notch_container">
       <div class="notch notch1">notch 1</div>
       <div class="notch notch2">notch 2</div>
       <div class="notch notch3">notch 3</div>
       <div class="notch notch4">notch 4</div>
       <div class="notch notch5">notch 5</div>
       <div class="notch notch6">notch 6</div>
       <div class="notch notch7">notch 7</div>
       <div class="notch notch8">notch 8</div>
       <div class="notch notch9">notch 9</div>
       <div class="notch notch10">notch 10</div>
       <div class="notch notch11">notch 11</div>
       <div class="notch notch12">notch 12</div>
       </div>
```

Comment: hmm. still doesnt work for some reason. I cant for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: actually ive got the first notch to rotate by changing the const to var, but trying to get all twelve notches to rotate. they all have a same class name as you can see. when i use the querySelectorALL method, it creates a new error about the setProperty methos a null.